# ShaderToy with SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, sprite-kit, shader

Can someone provide some direction on how to use code from the [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com) site in sprite kit?  This works with other shaders in an .fsh file but I can't seem to get any code from [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com) to work.   Im using the .sks file to add my SpriteNode to the scene. I apply the Custom Shader To the SpriteNode using the SKNode Inspector in interface builder.

Comment: I've never used sprite kit and have limited knowledge of Shadertoy, but my understanding is that Shadertoy has a number of uniform variables that it passes from the CPU to the shader. Probably SpriteKit doesn't have these variables, or uses different names for them than Spritekit, so there is no data for the shader to work with. This applies to anything listed under "Global Inputs" on the Shadertoy website. If you're using any of these, you should investigate whether sprite kit has any facility by which you can assign values to these variables, and use it to assign appropriate values.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to [sign-up/sign-in](https://www.shadertoy.com/signin) to access their API. Also, see the [SKShader](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html) docs

Comment: The following article can help you: http://battleofbrothers.com/sirryan/understanding-shaders-in-spritekit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to get a few shaders from the shadertoy web-site to work with Sprite Kit.

Firstly, in a shader where you see:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
```

change that to:

```
void main ()
```

Often, you will need to change the names of these variables:

`iGlobalTime` to   `u_time`

`fragColor` to  `gl_FragColor`

`fragCoord` to `gl_FragCoord`

`iResolution` to `u_sprite_size`

But in  iOS9, `u_sprite_size` is broken.  I have been following a solution suggested elsewhere by creating my own uniform & calling it `c_sprite_size` and setting the value in the sks file in the inspector.

A list of the SpriteKit uniforms is here:

[SKShader Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/)

Global variables don't seem to work that well in the fsh files;  I had to in a few cases change the code to pass the variables values around as a function parameter;  I am quite new to shader programming; there might be something else to get this working with how the variables are declared as uniform & varying etc.

I have experienced a few shaders not working on the simulator or in the Sprite Kit scene  editor  but will work on the device.  I have been using an iPhone 6s with iOS 9.2.

Lastly, it is worth noting when you run the app on an iDevice, shader compilation errors will show up in the debug console.  E.g.

```
Jet: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Compilation failed:
```

program_source:6:1: error: unknown type name 'precision'
precision mediump float;
^
program_source:6:19: error: expected unqualified-id
precision mediump float;
                  ^
program_source:8:1: error: unknown type name 'varying'
varying vec2 position;
^
program_source:8:13: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
varying vec2 position;
            ^

I was able to get some shaders fixed this way.

Comment: Hey mate, trying to get the shaders to work in spritekit from shadertoy. With your answer it helped me also. But ive come across a variable iMouse which i cannot find the correct reference for this. Have you come across this?

Comment: Hi,  offhand I don't know.  I think iMouse might be specific to running shaders in a web page.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I see that you've got a few shaders from shadertoy to work but I am having no luck. Long shot, but are you able to provide some of your examples of the shadertoy script vs spritekit script?    Would help me so much :)

Comment: I will see what I can dig up - it might be a day or two.

Comment: Thanks very much mate. Much appreciated :) If appropriate you can send the examples to krishpateluk@gmail.com

Comment: This project on Github has an example of a fragment shader converted to work with SpriteKit; there are multiple experiments in the project mostly with SceneKit.  The shader is associated with a node in the SKS file "Experiment.sks". You can see it working in the SK scene editor in Xcode. https://github.com/ManjitBedi/CubeTrip